# Convert the list of objects to JSON using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of data from my javascript function,

```
ID=1
Name=priya
Role=Teacher
category=staff
ID=2
Name=John
Role=Student
category=null
ID=3
Name=Maria
Role=Teacher
category=staff
ID=4
Name=Raja
Role=Student
category=null
```

I need to convert this json data as below,

```
JSON={
"Teacher":{ 
    "category":{  
        "Name"  : "ID"
        "Name"  : "ID"
        "Name"  : "ID"
}
},
"Student":{
    "Name":"ID"
    "Name":"ID"
    }
}
```

I have tried to write the jquery function and getting output as 'undefined'. here my code,

```
function convertJSON(input){
var jsonObj = [];
$(input['Role']).each(function(){           
                var name= $(this).attr("Name");         
                    var id = $(this).attr("ID");
                     var item = {};
                    item [name] =id;
                    jsonObj.push(item);
         });

    console.log(jsonObj);
}
```

Can anyone help me?...Thanks in advance
Note: If the category is null it should not be considered.

Comment: How actually you are getting the data such as ```ID=1
Name=priya
Role=Teacher ... ``` ??

Comment: Seconded, what exactly is input['Role'] and how are you getting this data?

Comment: @ManirajMurugan   As a list

Comment: In that input data I need only the value of role....I think i wrote code wrongly.....Since i am new to jquery @TimSheehan

Comment: @priya, If you are making simple words like this, then it is very very hard to give you answer.. The structure you are mentioning in question is not at all a valid data type.. Unless there is no enough information and detail explanation, it is difficult to get a solution sorry..